# Excel sum function that returns zero, if any value in the sum range contains zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like Excel to return answer as zero if any of the values in that sum range is zero.

I have tried a combination of logical tests, but I can't get what I want.

Answer (score 4):

My immediate reaction was also multiplication but perhaps less computationally intensive would be to sum only if a zero is not found in the source.

Assuming the array is `A1:C3`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C3,"=0")>0,0,SUM(A1:C3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could multiply all the values in the range. If one value is zero the result will be zero and then you can use that in a test to either multiply the sum by 0 or 1.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAX(0,MIN(RANGE))
```

will return the minimal positive integer value in the range if no zero is present, otherwise zero. change MIN to MAX to return the maximal positive integer value